# Can't remove .Rproj.user folder from untracked changes

Tags: r, git, terminal, rstudio

I can't remove `.Rproj.user` folder from untracked changes.

I tried using `git clean -d -f` to remove the `.Rproj.user` folder from untracked changes.  The terminal responds that it is `'Removing .Rproj.user'`.  But when I run git status again the `.Rproj.user` is still listed under untracked files.

Comment: If it’s untracked you’ll need to ignore the file.

Answer (score 2):

As @evolutionxbox says, you need to ignore this folder. This means you have to list it in the .gitignore file.
You can do it manually or better use ;
`usethis::use_git_ignore(".Rproj.user")`
This should do the trick. 
To know more about using git with R, I recommend reading this website : [happygitwithr.com/](http://happygitwithr.com/)